# please explain why private instance variable can be called using this instanceOfAClass.instanceVariable

Tags: java, private, instance-variables

Im trying some of the exercises in this link https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3f_OOPExercises.o be specific I'm on exercise 1.3

Main

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package example3;

/**
 *
 */
public class Example3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test program
        MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint(3, 0);
        MyPoint p2 = new MyPoint(0, 4);

        // Testing the overloaded method distance()
        System.out.println(p1.distance(p2));    // which version?
        System.out.println(p1.distance(5, 6));  // which version?
    }

}
```

MyPoint class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package example3;

/**
 */
public class MyPoint {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public MyPoint() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public MyPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * @return the x
     */
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @param x the x to set
     */
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setxy(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * @return the y
     */
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * @param y the y to set
     */
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")";
    }

public double distance(int x, int y) {   // this version takes two ints as arguments
   int xDiff = this.x - x;
   int yDiff = this.y - y;
   return Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);
}

public double distance(MyPoint another) { 
// this version takes a MyPoint instance as argument
   int xDiff = this.x - another.x;
   int yDiff = this.y - another.y;
   return Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);
}
}
```

Kindly check the method distance in MyPoint class. x and y are private instance variable. How come that the code is working even if I accessed x and y like this another.x and another.y ??

Comment: You can access private variables from inside the class that defines them. So any method in the class `MyPoint` can access `x` and `y` from any instance of `MyPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are accessing the private variables using the same class, you can access them.

So in short, you can access any of the private variables in an instance of class X as long as you are accessing it from another class X instance.